# How to create a spreadsheet script that moves to the next sheet tab every minute?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet displaying information on two monitors. The file has anywhere from 5 to 30 tabs. I have been trying to get the following script with a time-driven trigger to move from one sheet tab to the next every minute, however I have two problems:

1) - I need the loop to skip four tabs (they have fixed names) and I currently can't figure out a workable solution, and
2) - the time driven trigger of 1 minute is not doing anything, not working.

Here are two scripts I've been testing and tweeking to see if I find the one that works:

**Script 1:**

```
function MoveNext() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var nextSheetIndex = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1;

  if (nextSheetIndex > spreadsheet.getSheets().length) { nextSheetIndex = 1; }
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[nextSheetIndex - 1],true);
```

**And Script 2**: this one aims at skipping the four tabs I don't want to loop:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  switch (sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
    case "T1":
    case "T0":
    case "Summary Panel":
    case "Flight Info":
    case "Template":
      break;
    default:


      var nextSheetIndex = ss.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1;
      if (nextSheetIndex > ss.getSheets().length) {
        nextSheetIndex = 1;
      }
      ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[nextSheetIndex - 1], true);
```

Comment: Hey, i'm skipping specific sheets, theres 5 of them and they got fixed names. The others change everyday in number and names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add your timer code yourself, but here is an example of how to move to the next "approved" sheet.

```
function MoveNext() {
  var sheetsToSkip = ["Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet7"];
  var thisBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetCount = thisBook.getNumSheets();
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var thisSheetName = thisSheet.getName();
  var thisSheetIndex = thisSheet.getIndex() - 1;  //subtract one to get the array index
  var allSheets = thisBook.getSheets();

  var i = thisSheetIndex;
  var notDone = true;
  while (notDone) {
    if (i == (sheetCount-1)) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
    Logger.log('next sheet index is ' + i);
    var nextName = allSheets[i].getName();
    if (sheetsToSkip.indexOf(nextName) == -1) {
      var nextSheet = allSheets[i];
      Logger.log('next active sheet should be ' + nextSheet.getName());
      thisBook.setActiveSheet(nextSheet);
      notDone = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! thank you very much! this will help me in other similar scripts so again thank you